# Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: latex

I am using `iopart` template, and I do not know why get this error :

Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \begin
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin

I really appreciate any help

````
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
%\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
%\usepackage{iopams}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax

\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cotinv}{cot\,inverse}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\amscases\cases
\makeatletter
\def\cases{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\plaincases\amscases}
\def\plaincases#1{\begin{cases*}#1\end{cases*}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\newcommand{\acot}{\cot^{-1}}
\begin{document}

\title[]{}

\author{}
\author{}
\address{Department of}

\vspace{10pt}
\begin{indented}
\item[]November 2022
\end{indented}

\begin{abstract}
lll
\end{abstract}

%
% Uncomment for keywords
\vspace{2pc}
\noindent{\it Keywords}: electronics
%
% Uncomment for Submitted to journal title message
%\submitto{\JPA}
%
% Uncomment if a separate title page is required
\maketitle
% 
% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
\ioptwocol
%



\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}


\end{document}```
````

Comment: Can you add a link to where we can get the class from?

Comment: This class is related to iop journals that can be found here: https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate this instance. It first asked for the missing `iopart.cls` documentclass. I could get that from a GitHub repository belonging to Tianjin University named "etgroup". You can simply find it by searching "iop latex template" in Github. After the second compilation, it asked for a class dependency named `iopart10.clo`(it's available in the same repository).
Finally, after the third compilation, I could get a PDF output(Please see the figure attached).

**Solution**: If you are using a local LaTeX IDE/Studio, I recommend updating the packages you are using. Sometimes there are conflicts between some packages but they usually resolve quickly by releasing an update and you might see that there was nothing wrong with your commands.
Alternatively, you may try using an online LaTeX editor. They always have the last version of the most common packages and are equipped with multiple LaTeX render engine types.

[image: PDF render output]

Comment: I updated MIktex packages as you suggested and the problem has been solved. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Great! Just remember you need to put the `.cls` class files and other dependencies besides the main `.tex` file by default unless you define the path to them in the preamble.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I did this but unfortunately I got the class not found error. I asked this question before.

Comment: This means a `.sty` or `.cls` file is still missing. I cannot initiate a comment there. Can you also add a screenshot of the directory shown probably on the left side of your LaTeX editor to see the hierarchy of files? In that post not here.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. My laptop is not available. I upload the picture as soon as possible